# Can I sue the other person listed on the deed of my house?

Tags: mortgage

I need information about whether I can sue the other person on the deed of my house who has not paid their share of the mortgage after we agreed that we both would. My name is the only one on mortgage but both names appear on deed. Now I'm stuck with paying mortgage by myself.

Comment: More suitable for law.stackexchange.com, but unless you have some sort of contract that states you both will pay equally there's probably not much chance of winning.  Verbal contracts are binding, but all they have to do is deny the verbal contract and it will be tough to prove.  Since your name is the only one on the mortgage you're the only one that's legally obligated to pay it.

Comment: I'm assuming you're in the US.  If not please add the country this applies to.

Comment: Did the other person pay for half the house?  Or did you buy it and put both names on the deed?

Comment: Long story short, in the US you can pretty much sue anyone.  Written agreements will make this process easier than a verbal hand-shake agreement though.  However, even barring a written agreement there is a legal concept of "consideration" in contract law, the court may ask why the other person is on the deed for free.

Comment: You might want to sue the person that advised you to enter into this agreement.  Clearly it was a poor decision.

Comment: You can sue whoever you want, for anything you want. Perhaps you're wondering if you have a *good case* against this person.

Comment: If you are looking to sue someone, I would highly recommend paying for a lawyer's time to tell you if it's even worth considering, and to advise you of other avenues that might be available.

Answer (score 10):

You can sue to have the other person removed from the deed, and that may be an easy win if they have never paid any portion of the mortgage, but it's likely more complicated than that if the other party has made payments.

Are you worried because you can't afford the house without splitting the payments? If so you may just wish to sell the house and terminate the deal.

Answer (score 4):

> My name is the only one on mortgage but both names appear on deed. Now im stuck with paying mortgage by myself.

Most likely, yes.  The mortgage is just the responsibility to pay the loan on the house, and is not necessarily tied to ownership.

Can you sue?  Sure, but it might be tough to win.  If you have some sort of written agreement that both would pay that would help.  You could also argue that if they did not pay for half the house being on the deed could imply an agreement to pay for half the house through the mortgage.

Comment: The judge will go for fairness, but will go for stuff in writing first. As such, he will want to know a lot more about *why* choices were made that put both of you on the deed but only one on the mortgage.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, they are on the mortgage (the security instrument) because they have an ownership in the property that is being used as collateral for a loan, and they have to agree to have their interests encumbered in this way.  You would not have been able to obtain the loan without their signature on this document.

What they are NOT on is the promissory note, which is where you have agreed (solely) to repay the loan.  If you added them to the deed after you took our your mortgage loan, you have violated a term of your mortgage and the lender could move to accelerate your loan (demand it be paid off now); you are not allowed to change the ownership of the collateral without the lender's approval.  Keep making the payments on time and they won't have any reason to question you about this, if that is what you did.

Even though the amount may be small enough for small claims court, because you are dealing with real property encumbered by a mortgage you should probably retain an attorney to assist you with this because it can get complicated.

I get the impression that you do not have a written agreement or contract regarding these payments, so you will be burdened to providing some documentation that there was an agreement.  This could be in the form of you having evidence of past payments they have made to you, or mail/email/texts where they address the obligation.  If you have none of that, you are on very shaky ground to be able to get any relief.